# Sending files over the network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, file-transfer, windows-10

Is there an easy way to send files over a network?

Specifically between my desktop running Windows 7 that is using an Ethernet cord and a [Surface 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_3) running Windows 10 that is connected to the same network wirelessly. Homegroups and workgroups don't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you run ipconfig on each machine to see the IPs and verify the permissions (both local and share) on the two machines?

Comment: The easy way would be using homegroups or workgroup networking, perhaps it would be good to ask a new question to try and diagnose why there homegroups is not working. What does it say when you go to use the homegroups? Is it set up properly on both machines?

Comment: It can set up properly on both machines, but it appears that windows 10 isn't backwards compatible with windows 7 for homegroup.

Comment: How do I do that? I just see the general info when I run ipconfig like ip address.

Comment: Get IP Address of surface. Make share "everyone" then on PC \\IP\Share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a Windows share and dropping the files in there, then connecting to the share server from whichever machine you are transferring to. To do this, open "Computer Management." If you can't find it, search for it using the search bar under recent programs in the menu. Then navigate to "System Tools" and finally "Shares." These are all the share servers on your computer, and you can create a new one from here. Follow the instructions to create the share.

After the share is created, go to the client machine. On the client machine, open Windows explorer, and go to computer. Under the network tab, right click, and "add network location." Follow the instructions with information from the share you created, and you now have a connection between your two machines to transfer files :)

Answer (score 0):

In this day & age the easiest way I have found to keep everything up to date between multiple systems is simply to use some manner of cloud storage.

[Dropbox](http://dropbox.com), my personal preference.
[Here](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/running-out-room-dropbox-here-are-11-dropbox-alternatives-that-offer-way-more-free-cloud-storage.html) is a list of alternatives. Drive is the only one I have personally used & can also recommend.

Edit:
I know this doesn't directly answer your question & apologise for that. I have been away from Windows for some time now in favor of *nix based solutions. As such I don't know what network protocols and/or utilities are in use within Windows anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue was the fact that I named my surface and desktop the same name so I could not view the other in the network tab. Created a shared folder on the windows 7 machine and the files are showing up on both machines. Dropbox seems to actually have a LAN sharing setting, but I do not have enough storage space on it for that option to work and my internet is too slow to host to my other cloud storage options